# How to load data in UITableView cell from structure

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, struct

I am trying to load data from a structure to table view cell, I created a custom cell with three label in it. I have three text field in the view controller and a add button I want that when I fill these three text field and press add it will store these three values in a structure and reload the data of table view. Structure is in other file.

Here is code for structure in DataMaster.swift

```
struct jobData
{
    var CompanyName:Array<String> = ["ram"]
    var job:Array<String> = ["shyam"]
    var desc:Array<String> = ["dfdf"]

}
```

Code for addButton function

```
@IBAction func addButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

        var company = txtCompName.text
        var job = txtJob.text
        var description = txtDesc.text

        data.CompanyName.append(company)
        data.desc.append(description)
        data.job.append(job)
        self.jobTableView.reloadData()
        print(data.CompanyName)
        txtCompName.resignFirstResponder()
        txtJob.resignFirstResponder()
        txtDesc.resignFirstResponder()
    }
```

The problem is in this code

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath:indexPath) as jobTableViewCell
        cell.compLabel.text = data.CompanyName[indexPath.row]
        cell.jobLabel.text = data.job[indexPath.row]
        cell.descLabel.text = data.desc[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
```

when it reaches to this code to load data in table it crashes 
`Thread 1:EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=EXC_I386_BPT,subcode=0x0`)

[image: UI design]

Comment: did you created array of structure?

Comment: sir Ashish kakkad look at code , i used array in structure

Comment: I am not sir. I am just asking that you are created array of structure?  not that you are used array in structure. @SubhashSharma

Comment: @AshishKakkad, No I`m using structure of array. Do you have any solution dear?

Comment: Why you are creating properties as Array inside the structure. Instead you can create array of structures. Its easy.

Comment: @Amit89 can you describe as example

Comment: What value do you return in numberOfRowsInSection?. It should be count of one of your arrays in data structure ex. `data.CompanyName.count`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here below is code.

```
struct jobData
{
    var CompanyName:String!
    var job:String!
    var desc:String!
}
```

Take an array as `var datas = [jobData]()`

Now in Action method

```
@IBAction func addButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    var company = txtCompName.text
    var job = txtJob.text
    var description = txtDesc.text

    let dataObject = jobData(company: company, job: job, desc: description)
    datas.append(dataObject)
    self.jobTableView.reloadData()
    txtCompName.resignFirstResponder()
    txtJob.resignFirstResponder()
    txtDesc.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Now in cellForRowAtIndex method

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath:indexPath) as! jobTableViewCell
    let data = datas[indexPath.row]

    if let companyName = data.CompanyName  {
        cell.compLabel.text = companyName
    }

    if let job = data.job  {
        cell.jobLabel.text = job
    }

    if let descr = data.desc  {
        cell.descLabel.text = descr
    }

    return cell
}
```

in numberofRowsInSection method return `datas.count`
Check why data.CompanyName is empty and make sure all text field will have text.

Comment: after applying changes(as you explained above) app is crashed and showing : Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=EXC_I386_BPT,subcode=0x0)

Comment: Where exactly it is crashing?

Comment: when i tap the button, app is crashing

Comment: Remove the three line  txtCompName.resignFirstResponder() txtJob.resignFirstResponder() txtDesc.resignFirstResponder() and put break point and check where exactly it is crashing and let me know.

Comment: exactly app is crashed on:  cell.compLabel.text = data.CompanyName

Comment: Again it crashed at the same place : after first if condition on data.compLabel.text = companyname

Comment: I tried same here, it is working charm.  Check wether cell nil or not.